# How do I extend React components already in use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, prototype, extends

This applies to just about any scenario along these lines:

I have a React app that uses React Router `<Link>`s, and they are scattered throughout my app. I want to extend or prototype the `<Link>` component so that there is a new attribute when they are rendered. (I just want to add an attribute to all Link tags.)

How can I update the `Link` component that is being used throughout the app, to have a new attribute [without creating a new component, like `<CustomAttributeLink>`]?

Thanks

Comment: Do you usually write Kotlin? : ) I don't know any other languages that lets you "tack on" things on to objects/classes/functions you don't own. Anyway, that's not possible in JavaScript and so the solution is to create a custom component that wraps the original one. Abstracting libraries away from your code is generally a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by cloning the element, you should use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#react.cloneelement). To make the component usable everywhere, just create a new component using it, and export it.

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router";

const CustomLinkAttribute = React.cloneElement(Link, {
  newProp: "New prop val here"
});
export default CustomLinkAttribute;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the element and add the extra props using [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) e.g:

```
var clonedElementWithExtraProps = React.cloneElement(
    MainElement, 
    { newProp: "This is a new prop" }
);

Return clonedElementWithExtraProps;
```